# I am getting unexpected NaN value when trying pd.concat. How to deal with this? PCA vs T-SNE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to reduce the dimension of the data using PCA, however, when I use concat, it automatically generating a NaN value. Also the customer age has become float while it was int. Can someone please tell me how can I solve this problem?
Also it would be highly appreciated if you please tell me if I should use PCA or tSNE to visualize the data with 14 variables (in which there is a column which just contain 4 different variables (1,2,3,4) out of 12000 values, there are two columns with booleans).

[x and y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiNXR.png)
[image]

```
# Separating out the Demographic Data.

x = Demo_Data.values

# Separating out the Target as regions. 
y = df2.loc[:,['Customer_Age']].values

# Standardizing the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
x = scaler.fit_transform(x)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
Demography_Data = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = Demography_Data
             , columns = ['Demography_Data 1', 'Demography_Data 2'])
finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df2[['Customer_Age']]], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Can you print the `y` before concatenating?

Comment: @VivekKumar yes. I am adding the screenshot of the x and y, please find it in the pics.

Comment: Either you drop all rows containing any nans or you do  imputing/filling of nan values.

Comment: Check what is in `df2.index`, does it contain `0`?

Comment: @Dan  the index is non-null and the remaining data as well.   dtype='int64', name='Customer_Identity', length=10296

Comment: But does it contain `0`?

Comment: @Dan No. it doesn't. It starts from 1.

Comment: I think that's why you're getting a `NaN` at index `0` after you call `concat` then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index` in your `DataFrame`'s do not match:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([11,22,33])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([111,222,333], index=[1,2,3])
>>> pd.concat((df1,df2),axis=1)
      0      0
0  11.0    NaN
1  22.0  111.0
2  33.0  222.0
3   NaN  333.0
```

however:

```
>>> df2.index=df1.index
>>> pd.concat((df1,df2),axis=1)
    0    0
0  11  111
1  22  222
2  33  333
```

Comment: Thanks but this is what I am getting in error
 , "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 10296 elements, new values have 10297 elements"

Comment: I think there's a clue in there for you... how do you expect there not to be a `NaN` if your dataFrame's don't have the same number of rows!

Comment: yup.. finally.. it worked. Thanks a lot. It was my bad that I didn't perform principalDf.index=df2[['Customer_Age']].index